Issues Connecting to Snap Store on IPv6-only AWS Lightsail Instance running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
I've been experiencing issues connecting to the Snap Store using snapd on an IPv6-only AWS Lightsail instance running Ubuntu. Despite successful IPv6 connectivity tests, snapd fails to connect to the Snap Store, preventing me from installing or updating snaps.
Environment:
Cloud Provider: AWS Lightsail |
Instance Type: IPv6-only |
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS |
snapd Version:
snap    2.61.3+22.04,
snapd   2.61.3+22.04,
series  16,
kernel  6.5.0-1016-aws |
Steps Taken:
Confirmed Internet Connectivity: My instance has a public IPv6 address, and I've confirmed it can access the internet using ping6 ipv6.google.com, which works as expected.
Firewall Configuration: The instance's firewall rules allow outbound traffic on ports 22 (SSH), 80 (HTTP), and 443 (HTTPS) for any IPv6 address.
DNS Resolution Test: Using dig @2001:4860:4860::8888 snapcraft.io AAAA, I successfully resolved the Snap Store's domain to its IPv6 addresses.
Direct IPv6 Ping Test: I can ping the Snap Store's IPv6 addresses directly (e.g., ping6 2620:2d:4000:1::26), confirming reachability.
snapd Connectivity Issue: Despite the above, snapd cannot connect to the Snap Store. The logs indicate a timeout error when trying to reach api.snapcraft.io.
Also tried common fixes but its still not working.
Example:
killall snap-store
snap refresh
Additional Notes:
This issue occurs on a clean, newly provisioned IPv6-only instance with no custom proxies, VPNs, or unusual network configurations.
I have successfully SSH'd into the server, indicating no issues with inbound connectivity.
The problem does not occur in a dual-stack environment, suggesting it might be related to the IPv6-only setup.
Logs:
(Include relevant log snippets from journalctl -u snapd that show the errors you're encountering)
Questions:
Are there known issues with snapd connecting to the Snap Store over IPv6, specifically in cloud environments like AWS Lightsail?
Could there be specific configurations or considerations for snapd in IPv6-only setups that I might have missed?
Any suggestions for further troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your assistance and looking forward to any insights you may have.
